# Access the main mic in devices mics dual array

Tags: android

My application uses the following code to record audio:

```
this.recorder = new AudioRecord(1, sampleRate, channel, 2, iAudioBufferSize);
```

With normal devices, recording and recognizing is normal. However some customers feed back to me that their device is not working. Specifically the device Lenovo TB-J606F TAB.

When I checked the device I found that the device is dual array mics, so I think the problem is that the device is not in the correct mic stream.

So is there a way to confirm the correct stream that the device receives for recording, or merge the sound of the 2 mics to record and recognize?

P/S: Customers are far away from me and have no way to get their devices to test, I'm blind fix :(

Thanks for reading, pls help.I'm dev Unity

Answer (score 0):

i bought this laptop to my parents and they face the problem. when they try to speak with skype, viber etc, the noise reduction and their voice

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).